# Why am I getting "AccessDenied" from S3 DeleteObjects?

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm trying to delete a number of objects in an S3 bucket like so (Lambda / Node.js):

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: 'my-bucket',
    Delete: {
      Objects: [ 'my-bucket/dir/file1.json', 'my-bucket/dir/file2.json' ],
      Quiet: False
    }
  }
  const result = await s3.deleteObjects(s3Params).promise()
  return result
}
```

But I get:

```
{ 
  result: { 
    Deleted: [],
    Errors: [ 
        {Key: "my-bucket/dir/file1.json", Code: "AccessDenied", Message: "Access Denied"},
        {Key: "my-bucket/dir/file1.json", Code: "AccessDenied", Message: "Access Denied"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is my role policy:

```
{
    "RoleName": "S3CleanupRole", 
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17", 
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "s3:ListBucket", 
                    "s3:DeleteObject"
                ], 
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
                ], 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }, 
            {
                "Action": [
                    "DynamoDB:Query"
                ], 
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:514141358776:table/buckets-to-clean-out"
                ], 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "PolicyName": "S3CleanupPolicy"
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 3):

(Kudos to [Ravi Ramanujam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7648437/ravi-ramanujam) for this - his answer to [AWS S3 Access Denied on delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42658141/aws-s3-access-denied-on-delete/42674453/) helped me solve this problem.)

My policy is wrong. The permission for `s3:DeleteObject` applies only to the bucket `arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:514141358776:table/buckets-to-clean-out` and *not* any of its contents. The correct policy allows `s3:DeleteObject` on the bucket contents, viz:

```
{
    "RoleName": "S3CleanupRole", 
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17", 
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Action": [
                    "s3:ListBucket"
                ], 
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
                ], 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }, 
            {
                "Action": [
                    "s3:DeleteObject"
                ], 
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
                ], 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }, 
            {
                "Action": [
                    "DynamoDB:Query"
                ], 
                "Resource": [
                     "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:514141358776:table/buckets-to-clean-out"
                ], 
                "Effect": "Allow"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    "PolicyName": "S3CleanupPolicy"
}
```

The crucial piece is below. Note that the "Resource" section contains `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*` rather than just `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket`

```
 {
     "Action": [
         "s3:DeleteObject"
     ], 
     "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
     ], 
     "Effect": "Allow"
 }
```

Comment: Yes, most people see this issue when creating policies with `GetObject`. It can be a time-consuming lesson. See similar: [AWS STS to list buckets gives access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60291852/174777)